# JQuery Notification-System Offset when scrolling

Tags: jquery, notifications, offset

I'm making my own notification system, since I find a couple of lines of code are better than including a whole plugin with many features that aren't use, so please don't suggest any plugins.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PDa7a/

You can trigger notifications by pressing the `Click me!`-link in the body. As long as a user doesn't scroll, this will work nicely. However, when the user scrolls, the notifications aren't animated to the top of the screen, but rather to the center or so.

Here's the code:

```
var notificationHeight = 0;

function notification(message, style) {
    var message = $("<span class='notification' data-set='1'>" + message + "<span class='closenotification'>&#10006;</span></span>").appendTo("#notificationContainer");
    notificationHeight += message.outerHeight();
    console.log(notificationHeight);
    message.animate({
        top: notificationHeight - message.outerHeight() + "px"
    }, function () {
        //after start-animation
    }).on('click', function () {
        var thisser = $(this);
        if (thisser.data('set') == 1) {
            thisser.data("set", 0);
            thisser.css('z-index', '9');
            var thisheight = thisser.outerHeight();
            notificationHeight -= thisheight;
            thisser.nextAll().each(function () {
                $(this).animate({
                    top: $(this).offset().top - thisheight + 'px'
                }, {
                    queue: false
                });
            }); - thisser.animate({
                top: thisser.offset().top - thisheight + 'px'
            }, function () {
                thisser.remove()
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
thisser.animate({
    top: thisser.offset().top - thisheight + 'px'
}, function () {
    thisser.remove()
});
```

to

```
thisser.animate({
    top: thisser.position().top - thisheight + 'px'
}, function () {
    thisser.remove()
});
```

(`offset` to `position`).

Otherwise you get the wrong values.

Comment: Another issue is that when scrolled, triggering a notification makes the browser scroll to the top of the page